# How to use the hamilton method (largest remainder method) when the maximum amount of seats is limited

Tags: voting-theory

I hope this is the right place to ask even though the math behind it is quite easy, i have trouble with the application of the hamilton method on my problem.

The hamilton method/hare niemeyer method describes a system how to allocate seats in a parlamaint proportionally to the votes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method

I have a different problem but this method seems to be commonly used. I am working in an association which consists out of multiple smaller organisations. We have one big conference each year and each organisation has a number of seats according to the number of people in the organisation.
But we have a minimum number of 2 and a maximum number of 7 votes per organisation.

So when I calculate the percentages of the different organisations I end up with something like this:

organisations: 6

free seats: 28

Everyone gets 2 (minimum) so it is 20 to distribute:

orga1: 40,4%

orga2: 30.3%

orga3: 10.2%

orga4: 8.1%

orga5: 7.1%

orga6: 4.8%

So when we multiply the percentages with the free seats we end up with:

orga1: 5 seats (8 according to hamilton but only 5 allowed to make up a total of 7)

orga 2: 5 seats (same as orga 1 but with 6 allowed)

orga4: 1

orga5: 1

orga6: 0

remaining total: 8
Usally, when there are seats remaining, they are distributed according to the value after the dot but in this case, only orga 3, 4, 5 and 6 could get more seats. So when each orga got 1 seat, how do I distribute the remaining 4 seats?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a maximum and minimum number of representatives by group, then you would find life easier with a highest-averages method. With the largest remainder method you divide votes by seats, but this then hits the constraints as you describe - one possible solution is to keep adjust the denominator of that calculation until you get an acceptable answer within the constraints.

Using your numbers (the percentages add up to $100.9\%$ though this does not matter - you could use actual numbers rather than percentages and it would still work), the initial problem is that the constraints prevent you allocating all $28$ seats.  I think the calculations are something like the following (not quite the same as yours and I did not start giving everyone $2$ seats but used it as a constraint):

```
                        orga1:  orga2:  orga3:  orga4:  orga5:  orga6:  Total  Seats %/seat
Size                    40.4%   30.3%   10.2%   8.1%    7.1%    4.8%    100.9%  28    3.6%
Crude seat allocation   11.211  8.408   2.831   2.248   1.970   1.332   28      
Integer                 11.000  8.000   2.000   2.000   1.000   1.000   25      
Constraint              7       7       2       2       2       2       22      
Remainder if allowed                    0.831   0.248   -0.030  -0.668          
Highest remainder                       1       1                       2       
Total seats allocation  7       7       3       3       2       2       24
```

If you must do something like this, you could gradually increase reduce the % per seat required by increasing the notional number of seats.  I think using $40$ works and you get something like this:

```
                        orga1:  orga2:  orga3:  orga4:  orga5:  orga6:  Total  Seats %/seat
Size                    40.4%   30.3%   10.2%   8.1%    7.1%    4.8%    100.9%  40    2.5%
Crude seat allocation   16.016  12.012  4.044   3.211   2.815   1.903   40      
Integer                 16      12      4       3       2       1       38      
Constraint              7       7       4       3       2       2       25      
Remainder if allowed                    0.044   0.211   0.815   -0.097          
Highest remainder                       1       1       1               3       
Total seats allocation  7       7       5       4       3       2       28
```

which I think is a bit of a hack.

With a highest averages method, you still have the constraints of $7$ and $2$, so you find the averages, allocate the seats you must (the $2$s), and then allocate all the extra seats to the highest averages (but not exceeding the $7$s).  I think you get at table like this:

```
    orga1:  orga2:  orga3:  orga4:  orga5:  orga6:          
    40.4%   30.3%   10.2%   8.1%    7.1%    4.8%            
Divisor                                 
1   40.4%   30.3%   10.2%   8.1%    7.1%    4.8%            
2   20.2%   15.2%   5.1%    4.1%    3.6%    2.4%            
3   13.5%   10.1%   3.4%    2.7%    2.4%    1.6%            
4   10.1%   7.6%    2.6%    2.0%    1.8%    1.2%            
5   8.1%    6.1%    2.0%    1.6%    1.4%    1.0%            
6   6.7%    5.1%    1.7%    1.4%    1.2%    0.8%            
7   5.8%    4.3%    1.5%    1.2%    1.0%    0.7%    
 
Big  7       7       5       4       3       2
```

and if you start by taking the top two rows automatically and then the averages which are the next biggest, you hit $28$ seats allocated with the averages of about $2.0\%$ or more (the next highest is about $1.8\%$).  Again you could work out the averages with numbers rather than percentages.

I think this last method is easier to explain as meaningful rather than the earlier invention of notional seats and then losing them in the calculation.